# Как поймать событие столкновения двух элементов в игре на JS (не на canvas)

Tags: javascript

**привет сообщество, делаю игру, но есть проблема.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу поймать событие столкновения ракеты с астероидами, пробовал через offsetLeft и getBoundingClientRect. Не получилось, возможно не правильно использовал эти инструменты. Искал решение, но нахожу в основном примеры с canvas, которые не актуальны в моем случае.

Подробнее:

1. есть спрайт ракеты которую можно перемещать клавишами, само
   перемещение реализовано через style и позиционирование по оси X.
2. так же есть генерируемые каждые 2 секунды астероиды, позиция старта которых меняется через рандомизацию позиционирования по оси Х. Падают же они(смещение по Y) при помощи @keyframe.
3. Астероиды удаляются каждые 4ре секунды что бы не перегружать браузер.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Исправьте ваш вопрос, чтобы код был в текстовом блоке

Answer (score 0):

Добрый вечер дорогой автор, я не очень хорошо разбираюсь во всём этом, но вот что у меня получилось.
P.S : Прошу меня не бить

Я думаю, что самый простой способ спровоцировать "Game Over" это с помошью координат обьктов. Всё просто, при столкновений двух объектов просто будет выводится алерт и там вы сможете добавить свою функцию для оканчание игры.

```js
  const test = document.querySelectorAll("div");
  const test1 = test[0];
  const test2 = test[1];

  var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
    var temp1 = test1.getBoundingClientRect();
    var temp2 = test2.getBoundingClientRect();

    var block1Coordonate = temp1.y + test1.offsetHeight;
    var block2Coordonate = temp2.y;

    if(block1Coordonate == block2Coordonate){
      alert("Смерть");
      clearTimeout(intervalId);
    }
  }, 100);
```

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  body div{
    animation: test 1 5s linear;
  }

  @keyframes test {
    50%,100%{
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div style="width: 250px; height: 250px; background-color: red; transform: translateY(-100%);"></div>

<div style="width: 250px; height: 250px; background-color: yellow; transform: translateY(100%);"></div>
```